# The chart's excessive left and right shifting problem in a swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a line chart in swiftui. However, when trying to add a rulemark to the chart, it shifts excessively left and right. I would be very happy if you could help me with this. I also want to show the date as HH:mm on the x axis, for example (10:05, 10:10) My model is like this:

```
struct StockPriceData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var timestamp: Date
    var open: Double
    var high: Double
    var low: Double
    var close: Double
}

var stockData: [StockPriceData] = [
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695374220000), open: 0.86552, high: 0.86655, low: 0.8651, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695376800000), open: 0.86646, high: 0.86686, low: 0.86622, close: 0.86667),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695380400000), open: 0.86667, high: 0.86693, low: 0.86613, close: 0.86669),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695384000000), open: 0.86669, high: 0.86739, low: 0.86651, close: 0.86671),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695387600000), open: 0.8667, high: 0.86708, low: 0.86644, close: 0.86671),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695391200000), open: 0.86672, high: 0.86858, low: 0.86648, close: 0.86819),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695394800000), open: 0.86818, high: 0.86901, low: 0.8679, close: 0.86839),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695398400000), open: 0.86838, high: 0.86957, low: 0.86759, close: 0.8695),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695402000000), open: 0.86949, high: 0.86957, low: 0.86825, close: 0.86877),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695405600000), open: 0.86877, high: 0.86927, low: 0.86864, close: 0.86873),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695409200000), open: 0.86871, high: 0.86913, low: 0.86835, close: 0.86868),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695412800000), open: 0.86869, high: 0.86881, low: 0.868, close: 0.86809),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695416400000), open: 0.8681, high: 0.86856, low: 0.86802, close: 0.86831),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695420000000), open: 0.86829, high: 0.86841, low: 0.86796, close: 0.86826),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695596460000), open: 0.86686, high: 0.86808, low: 0.86653, close: 0.86781),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695600000000), open: 0.86771, high: 0.86825, low: 0.86761, close: 0.86811),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695603600000), open: 0.86811, high: 0.86842, low: 0.86773, close: 0.868),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695607200000), open: 0.86799, high: 0.86877, low: 0.86792, close: 0.86818),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695610800000), open: 0.86818, high: 0.86832, low: 0.86664, close: 0.86672),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695614400000), open: 0.86672, high: 0.8669, low: 0.86604, close: 0.86656),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695618000000), open: 0.86656, high: 0.86675, low: 0.8663, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695621600000), open: 0.86642, high: 0.86667, low: 0.86619, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695625200000), open: 0.86643, high: 0.86658, low: 0.86529, close: 0.86547),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695628800000), open: 0.86546, high: 0.8658, low: 0.86542, close: 0.86567)
]
```

My UI is like this:

````
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var stockDatas: [StockPriceData]  = stockData
    @State var currentActiveItem: StockPriceData?
    @State private var selectedDate: Date?
    @State private var selectedClose: Double?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ChartView
            .chartYScale(domain: stockDatas.map {$0.close}.min()!...stockDatas.map{$0.close}.max()!)
        
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(format: Date.FormatStyle())
            }
    }
    
    private var ChartView: some View {
        
        Chart {
            ForEach(stockDatas) {
                LineMark(x: .value("time", $0.timestamp),
                         y: .value("price", $0.close))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
                
                AreaMark(x: .value("time", $0.timestamp),
                         yStart: .value("Min", stockData.map{$0.close}.min()!),
                         yEnd: .value("Max", $0.close)
                ).foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient.init(colors: [Color.green, .clear]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)).opacity(0.1)
                
                /*.accessibilityLabel("\($0.timestamp)")
                 .accessibilityValue("\($0.close) ")*/
                
            } //.symbol(Circle())
            
            if let selectedDate = selectedDate, let selectedClose = selectedClose {
                
                RuleMark(x: .value("Selected Date", selectedDate))
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                
                    .annotation(position: .top, alignment: .top) {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Close: \(selectedClose)")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                        }
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .fill(Color.gray)
                        )
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
            }
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-23, height: 200)
            .chartOverlay { proxy in
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    let origin = geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin
                                    let location = CGPoint(
                                        x: value.location.x - origin.x,
                                        y: value.location.y - origin.y
                                    )
                                    
                                    if let (date, close) = proxy.value(at: location, as: (Date, Double).self) {
                                        selectedDate = date
                                        selectedClose = close
                                    }
                                }
                                .onEnded { _ in
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
    }
}```

I only want the incoming time data to appear on the x-axis.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you are looking for:

```
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(format: .dateTime.hour().minute())
}
```

and

```
.chartXScale(domain: stockDatas.map {$0.timestamp}.min()!...stockDatas.map{$0.timestamp}.max()!)
```

But there seems to be something wrong with your test data. Using `addingTimeInterval(1695374220000)` would add something with 4 trailing 0's which results in approx 3 hours of difference in each point??

Comment: addingTimeInterval(1695374220000)  Is the data coming from the back side wrong or is it the parameter I use? How can I fix it?

Comment: Thank you. I think there is a mistake, we will fix it. Now a problem has arisen: the rule mark shows a value somewhere other than the chart. how can i block it. In other words, it shows value even in a small place outside the chart. Also, the rulemark is slipping, how can I prevent it? I want to add date in addition to the rule brand close value, I want it to display both date and close values in the relevant place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full test example:

```
struct StockPriceData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var timestamp: Date
    var open: Double
    var high: Double
    var low: Double
    var close: Double
}

var stockData: [StockPriceData] = [
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169537422), open: 0.86552, high: 0.86655, low: 0.8651, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169537680), open: 0.86646, high: 0.86686, low: 0.86622, close: 0.86667),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169538040), open: 0.86667, high: 0.86693, low: 0.86613, close: 0.86669),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169538400), open: 0.86669, high: 0.86739, low: 0.86651, close: 0.86671),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169538760), open: 0.8667, high: 0.86708, low: 0.86644, close: 0.86671),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169539120), open: 0.86672, high: 0.86858, low: 0.86648, close: 0.86819),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169539480), open: 0.86818, high: 0.86901, low: 0.8679, close: 0.86839),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169539840), open: 0.86838, high: 0.86957, low: 0.86759, close: 0.8695),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169540200), open: 0.86949, high: 0.86957, low: 0.86825, close: 0.86877),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169540560), open: 0.86877, high: 0.86927, low: 0.86864, close: 0.86873),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169540920), open: 0.86871, high: 0.86913, low: 0.86835, close: 0.86868),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169541280), open: 0.86869, high: 0.86881, low: 0.868, close: 0.86809),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169541640), open: 0.8681, high: 0.86856, low: 0.86802, close: 0.86831),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169542000), open: 0.86829, high: 0.86841, low: 0.86796, close: 0.86826),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169559646), open: 0.86686, high: 0.86808, low: 0.86653, close: 0.86781),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169560000), open: 0.86771, high: 0.86825, low: 0.86761, close: 0.86811),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169560360), open: 0.86811, high: 0.86842, low: 0.86773, close: 0.868),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169560720), open: 0.86799, high: 0.86877, low: 0.86792, close: 0.86818),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169561080), open: 0.86818, high: 0.86832, low: 0.86664, close: 0.86672),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169561440), open: 0.86672, high: 0.8669, low: 0.86604, close: 0.86656),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169561800), open: 0.86656, high: 0.86675, low: 0.8663, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169562160), open: 0.86642, high: 0.86667, low: 0.86619, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169562520), open: 0.86643, high: 0.86658, low: 0.86529, close: 0.86547),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(169562880), open: 0.86546, high: 0.8658, low: 0.86542, close: 0.86567)
]


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var stockDatas: [StockPriceData]  = stockData
    @State var currentActiveItem: StockPriceData?
    @State private var selectedDate: Date?
    @State private var selectedClose: Double?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ChartView
            .padding()
    }
    
    private var ChartView: some View {
        
        Chart {
            ForEach(stockDatas) {
                LineMark(x: .value("time", $0.timestamp),
                         y: .value("price", $0.close))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
            }
            
            if let selectedDate, let selectedClose {
                let relativePos = Double(stockDatas.firstIndex(where: {$0.timestamp >= selectedDate}) ?? 0) / Double(stockDatas.count)
                RuleMark(x: .value("Selected Date", selectedDate))
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .annotation(position: .top, alignment: relativePos < 0.6 ? .leading : .trailing) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Date: \(selectedDate.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))")
                            Text("Close: \(selectedClose)")
                        }
                        .font(.caption)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .fill(Color.gray)
                        )
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
            }
        }
        .chartXScale(domain: stockDatas.map {$0.timestamp}.min()!...stockDatas.map{$0.timestamp}.max()!)

        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .hour, count: 2)) { _ in
                AxisGridLine()
                AxisTick()
                AxisValueLabel(
                    format: .dateTime.hour().minute())
            }
        }

        .chartYScale(domain: stockDatas.map {$0.close}.min()!...stockDatas.map{$0.close}.max()!)

        .frame(height: 200)
        .chartOverlay { proxy in
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                let origin = geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin
                                let xPosition = value.location.x - origin.x
//                                let yPosition = value.location.y - origin.y
                                selectedDate = proxy.value(atX: xPosition, as: Date.self)
                                if let selectedDate, selectedDate >= stockDatas.map({$0.timestamp}).min()! {
                                    selectedClose = stockDatas.first(where: {$0.timestamp >= selectedDate })?.close
                                } else {
                                    selectedClose = nil
                                }
                            }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]